# Weird Issues with Parity

Tags: web3js, parity, myetherwallet

I just installed Parity (1.8.2) and made sure that it is fully synced, and am running into a couple of weird issues. (I installed Parity on a MacBook via Homebrew, config is all at default values)

1. I can connect to my local node using MetaMask via http://localhost:8545, but cannot connect to it using MEW (downloaded/offline version). I keep getting this error:

> Could not connect to the node. Refresh your page, try a different node (upper right corner), check your firewall settings. If custom node, check your configs.

I notice that I've a similar issue as described here: https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet/issues/922, I don't see a Request Payload.

2. When using Parity's Javascript console, commands like `web3.eth.blockNumber`, `web3.eth.syncing` all work and return values. However, when I install web3.js via npm, and then run the following:

`var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545'));`

Commands like `web3.eth.blockNumber` all return undefined. However, `web3.eth.getBlockNumber().then(console.log);` returns a value.

Thanks for the help!

Update:
I've also tried all of the below commands (or combination of them):

`parity --jsonrpc-cors '*' --jsonrpc-hosts all --jsonrpc-interface all`

`parity --jsonrpc-cors '*' --jsonrpc-hosts all --jsonrpc-interface all --rpccorsdomain 127.0.0.1`

None of them work. MEW is throwing this error (in Console):

> index.html:1 Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8545/: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, `parity --jsonrpc-cors null` did the trick. It disables CORS though AFAIK, but now my local MEW is able to connect to my local parity.

However, when using web3.js, I am still getting undefined, e.g.

`var Web3 = require('web3');
var web3 = new Web3();
web3.setProvider(new web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545'));
console.log(web3.eth.blockNumber);`

The output of the last line returns undefined.

Answer (score -1):

+1 @shuxy ,I had the same problem when I was using `--rpccorsdomain "*"`, but `--jsonrpc-cors null` solved the problem.